# Event Sourcing - Clarification on when Events are added to Event Store

Tags: c#, event-sourcing

**EDIT**

The architecture described in question was completely off. After spending some time I stumbled upon this article that was extremely helpful understanding Event sourcing: http://www.andreavallotti.tech/en/2018/01/event-sourcing-and-cqrs-in-c/

**END OF EDIT**

I am building a system based on DDD, Event Sourcing and CQRS. I have two databases and two Entity Framework contexts. First database is used for Normalized data, second for Events.

I also have the following Aggregate Root:

```
public class Order : Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
   private Order() 
   {
      this.AddDomainEvent(new OrderCreatedDomainEvent(this));
   }
   
   public static Order CreateOrder => new Order();
}
```

And using MediatR and I have the following Create Order command handler:

```
public class CreateOrderCommandHander : ICommandHandler<CreateOrderCommand>
{
   private readonly IOrderRepository _orderRepository;

   public async Task<Unit> Handle(CreateOrderCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
      // Creating new order which has OrderCreatedDomainEvent domain event
      var order = Order.CreateOrder();
      this._orderRepository.AddOrder(order);
      // Saving created order
      await this._orderRepository.UnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
      //...
   }
}
```

The question I have is - when exactly does `OrderCreatedDomainEvent` event gets fired and consequently added to Event Store? Is it **before** or **after** a new record is added & saved using `IOrderRepository` (normalized data database)?

If I had to guess - before, since Event Store is source of truth and it must always contain the latest state of the system. If I were to add record to Normalized database first, Event store would be out of sync.

In [this example](https://github.com/EduardoPires/EquinoxProject/blob/master/src/Equinox.Infra.Data/Context/EquinoxContext.cs) there is a `Commit` function that dispatches domain events **before** saving anything to normalized database. Is this the correct approach or just one of the possible approaches to it?

Comment: One thing that comes to my mind is that you're mixing two ideas in one place, and it's hard to solve this problem in a manner that you've chosen to create the system.  

Are you doing EventSourcing system, and have Events as a structure for your source of truth? Then this is should be your normalized data, and other things should be denormalized projections.  
Or, are you doing Audit Log in form of events, as side effect of state change to your aggregate? Then events are just side effect registered later, but your aggregate based on state is your main source of truth.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm only starting out with Event Sourcing. I was trying to follow the repository because it said it was implementing Event Sourcing. But something didn't seem quite right. As you mentioned, it seems as if all it's doing here is just creating audit log. Correct me if I'm wrong - but in CreateOrderCommandHander I should just add event to Event Store and then have an Event/Notification of some sort to create Read Model.

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to read more about Event Sourcing itself, before trying to implement the whole thing together with Projections, in a tool, that's not made for this (Entity Framework in this case). Event Sourcing is about saving stream of events. If you need denormalized data then you should use Projections, that are done by having Observator on new changes, which will run process of saving denormalized data in you read only database.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Maybe I got everything mixed up and I really need to get more studying before I start creating anything.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of an odd setup.

The way I've always solved it is to have the event being generated as the first step. Any relational projections can then subscribe to the events they are interested in and save that down.

You'll want to account for messages going missing or coming in the wrong order. You'll find at some point you'll need to replay all of the events - be a good idea to build the projections to be able to handle this.

One way is to store a local copy of those events with the projection, then you can tell if the event is the latest or a historic one which may require different logic (to rewrite the past if you will).